# How to find maximum consecutive occurrences of a substring in a string?

Tags: python, regex

I want a function that will take a full string and a sub-string and returns the maximum consecutive occurrences of that sub-string. I know I have to use regular expressions but I am not very familiar with the syntax and I'm a little stuck.

So it should work something like this:

```
import re

def get_max(substring, fullstring):
        ???? #TO-DO
        return max

print(get_max(foo, foofoofooxxfoofoo)

Output: 3
```

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a programming service. What have you tried, and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

Using `re`:

```
import re

def get_max(substring, full_string):
  pattern = "(?=((" + re.escape(substring) + ")+))"
  matches = re.findall( pattern, full_string )
  return max(len(m[0]) // len(substring) for m in matches


print(get_max('foo', 'foofoofooxxfoofoo'))
```

OUTPUT:

```
3
```